# Aggregating point data into polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, aggregation

I would like to aggregate point statistics to a specific polygon layer which is a 100*100m raster.

The point dataset includes address data of buildings and their heating energy consumption. So the output should be a sort of heat density map with average heat energy consumption per hectare (for example).

So this is the attribute I want to aggregate on the 100*100m Raster:

[image: Attribute of energy consumption]

I tried algorithms like "Point statistics for polygon" or "v.vect.stats" where the first one was not able to create the output layer. You can see the settings below. I uploaded the protocol-file [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eriROLRb56GCfDl9n4RxT3acVxInq21w/view?usp=sharing).
[image: Settings Point statistics for polygon]

With "v.vect.stats" an output-layer is created but without calculations.

Settings:

[image: Sittings v.vect.stats]

Output:

[image]

The datatype of the field is "Real" and I deleted all fields with "NULL" but there were no improvements on the output.

Does anybody have experienced the same problems?

Any ideas what another factors could be why those algorithms don't work for me?

I use QGIS-Version 3.12.1-București - maybe this could be the problem?

Edit 28.02.2021:
This is the protocol of "point statistics for polygons" after shortening the attribute names:

```
QGIS-Version: 3.12.1-București
QGIS-Codeversion: 121cc00ff0
Qt-Version: 5.11.2
GDAL-Version: 3.0.4
GEOS-Version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ-Version: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020
Verarbeite Algorithmus…
Algorithmus Point statistics for polygons startet…
Eingabeparameter:
{ 'AVG ' : False, 'DEV ' : False, 'FIELDS' : 'XX_HWB', 'FIELD_NAME' : 2, 'MAX ' : False, 'MIN ' : False, 'NUM ' : False, 'POINTS' : 'D:/00_Chris/01_Uni/00_Masterarbeit/PC/1_Basisdaten/WZ_Adr_point_komplett.shp', 'POLYGONS' : 'D:/00_Chris/01_Uni/00_Masterarbeit/PC/7_QGIS/export/shape/LAEA_Raster_zugeschnitten.shp|layername=LAEA_Raster_zugeschnitten', 'STATISTICS' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SUM ' : True, 'VAR ' : False }

shapes_polygons "Point Statistics for Polygons" -POINTS "D:/00_Chris/01_Uni/00_Masterarbeit/PC/1_Basisdaten/WZ_Adr_point_komplett.shp" -POLYGONS "D:/00_Chris/01_Uni/00_Masterarbeit/PC/7_QGIS/export/shape/LAEA_Raster_zugeschnitten.shp" -FIELDS "XX_HWB" -FIELD_NAME 2 -SUM true -AVG false -VAR false -DEV false -MIN false -MAX false -NUM false -STATISTICS "C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_mNhjBc/40c67d2b430642ceb59f592ee18be2b9/STATISTICS.shp"
D:\00_Chris\01_Uni\00_Masterarbeit\PC\7_QGIS\projekte>PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\qt5\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\WBem;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.12/apps\saga-ltr;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.12/apps\saga-ltr\modules

D:\00_Chris\01_Uni\00_Masterarbeit\PC\7_QGIS\projekte>call saga_cmd shapes_polygons "Point Statistics for Polygons" -POINTS "D:/00_Chris/01_Uni/00_Masterarbeit/PC/1_Basisdaten/WZ_Adr_point_komplett.shp" -POLYGONS "D:/00_Chris/01_Uni/00_Masterarbeit/PC/7_QGIS/export/shape/LAEA_Raster_zugeschnitten.shp" -FIELDS "XX_HWB" -FIELD_NAME 2 -SUM true -AVG false -VAR false -DEV false -MIN false -MAX false -NUM false -STATISTICS "C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_mNhjBc/40c67d2b430642ceb59f592ee18be2b9/STATISTICS.shp"
Error: no attributes in selection
Error: executing tool [Point Statistics for Polygons]
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: shapes_polygons
library : Polygons
tool : Point Statistics for Polygons
author : V. Olaya, O. Conrad (c) 2005, 2010
processors : 8 [8]
____________________________

Load shapes: D:/00_Chris/01_Uni/00_Masterarbeit/PC/1_Basisdaten/WZ_Adr_point_komplett.shp...


Parameters

Points: WZ_Adr_point_komplett
Attributes: <no attributes>
Polygons: LAEA_Raster_zugeschnitten
Statistics: Statistics
Sum: yes
Mean: no
Variance: no
Deviation: no
Minimum: no
Maximum: no
Count: no
Field Naming: original name

D:\00_Chris\01_Uni\00_Masterarbeit\PC\7_QGIS\projekte>exit
Ausführung nach 5.40 Sekunden abgeschlossen
Ergebnisse:
{'STATISTICS': 'C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_mNhjBc/40c67d2b430642ceb59f592ee18be2b9/STATISTICS.shp'}

Lade Ergebnis Layer
Die folgenden Layer wurden nicht erzeugt.<ul><li>C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_mNhjBc/40c67d2b430642ceb59f592ee18be2b9/STATISTICS.shp</li></ul>Im 'Protokoll-Fenster' im QGIS-Hauptfenster sind mehr Informationen zur Ausführung des Algorithmus zu finden.
```

This is how my layer looks like:

[image: Input]

This is how the wanted output should look like:
[image]

Comment: Would u share your layers (if possible) ?

Comment: Please try the native "Join Attributes by Location (Summary)" tool instead.

Comment: @snaileater sorry, I can´t share those layers due to sensible data. 
@ bugmenot123 thank´s for the advice, unfortunately it didn´t work. The joined fields are also empty (NULL). Any other ideas?

Comment: Looking at the linked SAGA protocol file, I see `Error: no attributes in selection` . Can you perhaps change the field name ("Gebäude_WBS_Alter_2020_4-Join_Table_Gesamt_HWB")  to a simpler name without an umlaut and give it a try again?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I registered myself so I´m the OP of this thread. I don´t think that this is the problem. I tried other attributes with shorter field names like "BGF". best regards
Chris

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your Input! The accounts should be merged now. 
@Kazuhito: I tried to use XX_HWB instead. No changes in the output. Any other ideas? The fielddatatypes should be correct (REAL)...

Comment: Chris, do you still see the same error message, or is it different now?

Comment: Yeah, the message is the same. Maybe it´s because of the amount of decimal places? - i pasted the message in the main poste above

Comment: It always says "no attributes in selection" I don´t know why...

Comment: Does anybody know any other tool for this kind of analysis? I changed the Version of QGIS but it didn´t help either...

Answer (score 2):

If I have well understood the question, the process if very simple since you can achieve what you are looking for with a single tool: "Join attributes by location (summary)" (see bugmenot123 recommendation in the comments part above)

- Input layer: the polygon grid
- Join layer: the points layer
- Fields to summarize: the column containing the heat energy consumption values
- Summaries to calculate: choose mean and/or others summaries (sum, min, max etc.)

Output: a new layer is created with a column "mean_value"

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

I used the extension "Add spreadsheet layer" to import join tables for my layers. BUT those imported fields had no "Lengh" and "Precission" defined (screenshot).
[image]

I solved the problem by creating new fields and pasting the values using the field calculator.

Comment: The dB Manager lets you construct SQL queries between 2 layers that will handle this. I would convert buildings to points from their centroids first, however, so that you don't use the same building twice.